# One-Page Scrolling inside a div HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-scrollify, onepage-scroll

I am working on this website (HTML5, CSS3, and JS) it has 2 divs (header and footer) which have CSS `position: fixed`, and there is a center div which has `position:absolute` and contains the content.

What I would like to do is implement scroll snapping within this center div which has absolute positioning. But for some reason I am unable to do this. This is the jquery plug-in I am trying to use: https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll

Can you guys please help me?

Here is a JSFiddle with the set up im trying: https://jsfiddle.net/icyyd/dswsg96d/

Comment: I have tried it with Scrollify as well but that hasnt worked for me either. When I get rid of the positioning somehow it works, but on the full page, which i dont want as my content is only in the center "content" div.

Comment: Do you mean to hide the scroll bar and yet still scrollable?

Comment: This help? https://jsfiddle.net/dswsg96d/1/

Answer (score 1):

you have to give certain fixed height to container then apply `overflow` property to auto. When content of container exceeds that certain fixed height it will give you scrolling inside container. Refer below :

```
div.container{
 height: 80vh; //making height fixed in order to implement overflow property
 overflow: auto; //it will give you scroll effect when content height exceeds 80vh;
}
```

Remember give height a fixed height i.e. either in px/vh/vw. It won't work if you give relative height like `%` 
hopefully it helps